# JavaScript Attribute Selector: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm trying to select an element with JavaScript using an attribute selector but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

### HTML

```
<a href="#incorporate">Incorporate</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="application/javascript">
document.querySelector( 'a[href="#incorporate"]' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( eventObj ) {
    // Do something.
} );
</script>
```

In Chrome's DevTools, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Where is the script in your page? Also, no need for the type on the script tag.

Comment: You're right. I needed to add document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded' ) because the element wasn't loaded yet, thus the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the sintaxy is correctly. If you test your code in W3Schools editor.
Your code is working.